# Pass id or paramter when redirected ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass id when user clicks on a button and is redirected to another page.

I am using react router, but unable to pass id. So far I tried below code:

```
<Route path="/editproject/:id" component={EditProject}/>
```

when user clicks on button :

```
if (this.state.switchEdit) {
  redirect = <Redirect to="/editproject/": {this.state.project.id} />
}

render(){
  return (
    { redirect }
  )
}
```

How can I pass id (this.state.project.id)?

Comment: Use: `to={\`/editproject/:${this.state.project.id}\`}`

Comment: Got it and how can I get this id in another page?

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about the [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to concat string.

```
<Redirect to={`/editproject/${this.state.project.id}`} />
```

To get the params back you can use that code to retrieve from the params.

```
this.props.match.params.id
```

In your case, you are using **:id**, that's why the code above use `.id`

```
<Route path="/editproject/:id" component={EditProject}/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `template literals` to pass the parameter

```
if (this.state.switchEdit){
    redirect=<Redirect to=`/editproject/:${this.state.project.id}` />
}

render(){
    return(
         {redirect}
    )
}
```

and Read it from `match` like `this.props.match.params.id` in the targetted component

Answer (score 0):

change you code to

```
if (this.state.switchEdit){
        redirect=<Redirect to={`/editproject/:${this.state.project.id`} />
    }

    render(){
               return(
                         {redirect}
              )
           }
```

i made use of template literals

you can access the id through the props of your component

> this.props.match.params.id

Answer (score 0):

You can access the params in another page using: `props.match.params.whatever_was_passedinURL`

Check the following example...

```
// All route props (match, location and history) are available to User
function User(props) {
  return <h1>Hello {props.match.params.username}!</h1>;
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <Route path="/user/:username" component={User} />
  </Router>,
  node
);
```